# How do you package compiled Coldfusion code using the command prompt instead of the Coldfusion Administrator html interface?

Tags: coldfusion, compilation, packaging

I'm trying to automate the process of packaging compiled Coldfusion code and the first step is to figure out how to override the user interface and call the actual code that packages the compiled coldfusion code (compiled using the cfcompile utility) inside war files.

Additional info:

Writing an app that calls cfcompile.bat and compiles Coldfusion code is fairly straightforward. The part that I'm having trouble with is the part that consists of packaging the compiled Coldfusion code. This is normally done using the Administrator tool (an html file) that comes with Coldfusion 9.

My goal is to package the code without using that tool, but other than making POST requests to that html file I have no idea how to access the actual tool that is used by the html page.

(By the way, I'm not familiar with ANT scripts, so if someone can offer a solution that can be implemented from the command prompt I'd appreciate it)

Comment: What version of CF are you interested in? ColdFusion 10+ will be different from CF9-.

Comment: I'm interested in Coldfusion 9.

Answer (score 2):

I'll admit I need to finish up some documentation, but it's a lot better than other options.

Check out https://github.com/orangexception/CFCompile-Pass-All

cfcompile-pass-all.bat is based on the cfcompile supplied with ColdFusion, but it actually works and is parameter driven.

Put `cfcompile-pass-all.bat` in `/WEB-INF/cfusion/bin` (These files use findjava.bat & findjava.sh)

Then you end up calling it like this...

`${sCFwwwrootPath}/WEB-INF/cfusion/bin/cfcompile-pass-all.bat ${sCFwwwrootPath}/WEB-INF/cfusion ${sCFLibPath}/jrun.jar ${sCFwwwrootPath}/WEB-INF ${sCFwwwrootPath} ${sCFAppPath} ${sCFAppCompiledPath}" />`

If you're looking at doing a complete source to compiled to WAR (to EAR) build, then check out the Ant script. It does everything for you.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at 2 step process: compilation & packaging. I clicked on that link you gave me but did not find any ANT file. where can I find it?

Comment: I suggest creating an empty WAR/EAR file using the CFIDE before you start. Put in your serial key, etc. as needed. Don't include the actual source or compile it during that step.

Afterwards, check out the build.xml and follow the workflow. Take note of the comments and try and follow what's going on before plugging in your values. I have the CFIDE turned off in that build file, so you'll probably want to uncomment that.

Comment: seems like you got it all working but the part I need to know is how to build the WAR file in such a way that I end up with the standard CFIDE/snapshots/WEB-INF/META-INF directories and files under those directories. running something like jar -cvf test.war * doesn't output the kind of war file I'm looking for. I'm guessing that your script does all that but I'm looking for the command line that does just that and nothing else

Comment: Sorry, I've been a bit swamped. Ping me on Twitter @orangexception and we can DM for new issues.